# Is there any polyfill for WebSQL using IndexedDB?

Tags: html, indexeddb, web-sql, shim

I wanted to use WebSQL in firefox and chrome packaged app.

I know that IndexedDBShim is a polyfill for IndexedDB using WebSQL,

conversely, is there any polyfill for WebSQL using IndexedDB?

Answer (score 1):

No. It's theoretically possible that one could exist, but it'd be a ton of work, so I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: I've seen a websql shim with base sql support, and I can't find it now.

Answer (score 0):

YDN-DB looks like it supplies a polyfill for WebSQL on top of IndexedDB https://yathit.github.io/ydn-db/doc/setup/polyfill.html